# opencv,jni CV_8UC1 type is incompatible with mixChannels()

Tags: c++, image, opencv, java-native-interface, computer-vision

i am developing an android application which process live camera stream frame by frame(to detect squares).in preview call back it passes image frame as a byte array.in my opencv function it coverts that byte array to a mat object.i need to use `mixchannels()` function in opencv .i think my mat object is incompatible with `mixchannels()`because it Struck there.any suggestions how to solve it.when i replace `image` with `image1` it Struck there too.please help.thank you & have a nice day!here is my code.

```
 JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_tutorial3_Sample3View_FindFeatures(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz, jint width, jint height, jbyteArray yuv, jintArray rgba)
```

{

`jbyte* _yuv  = env->GetByteArrayElements(yuv, 0);`

`jint*  _rgba = env->GetIntArrayElements(rgba, 0);`

```
//Mat myuv(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);
Mat image(height + height/2, width,  CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);//byte array in to mat object
Mat image1(height + height/2, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char *)_yuv);
Mat mrgba(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char *)_rgba);
Mat mgray(height, width, CV_8UC1, (unsigned char *)_yuv);


cvtColor(image, mrgba, CV_YUV420i2RGB ,4);




vector<vector<Point> > squares;//
vector<vector<Point> > contours;//
jint Area=0;
int thresh = 50, N = 10;

Mat pyr, timg, gray0(image.size(), CV_8U), gray;

pyrDown(image, pyr, Size(image.cols/2, image.rows/2));//reduces noice of the image,if i put'image1' here it struck too
pyrUp(pyr, timg, image.size());//reduces noice of the image


//for loop to find squares in every color plane of the image
for( int c = 0; c < 3; c++ )
{
int ch[] = {c, 0};
    mixChannels(&timg, 1, &gray0, 1, ch, 1);//code struck here.if i replace 'c' with '1' it workes
```